# how to catch the general node/add form?

Tags: php, drupal-6, nodes

I have a custom module and want to catch node/add , but inside form `hook_nodeapi()` it doesn't show up.

I need this, to restrict access to the general node creation overview form. Setting the rights is no solution for me, because my users need the right "create content"

Comment: If the users don't have permission to _create <content_type> content_ then that page won't be of much use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6). It should be able to do what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks but doesn't . it catches all forms but not the listing of the node/add page. I was confused when noticing that

Answer (score 0):

Drupal node module already provides the permissions for each content type so you can define permissions in admin/user/permissions page. Alternatively you can define your own permission using `hook_perm` in your custom module and use that permissions in your custom module.